# Update android app if sql value is changed

Tags: java, sql

I have email_status field in users column
This email_status is INT(2) can be 1 or 0
When email_status is 0, then in client I need to see - "status 0"
When email_status is 1, then in client I need to see - "status 1"

Problem
When I change in DB to 0, REBUILD(!) app, then OK
When I change in DB to 1, REBULT(!) app, then OK

But, Why I cannot see results without REBUILDING app?

I've tried the code bellow

```
        userDTO = prefrence.getParentUser(Consts.USER_DTO);
            if(userDTO.getEmail_status() == 1) {
                ProjectUtils.showToast(getActivity(), "statis1");
            }
                if(userDTO.getEmail_status() == 0) {
ProjectUtils.showToast(getActivity(), "status0");
                }
....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reloading the app. I think rebuilding the app is not required for database changes.